# Пишем одно, говорим другое

Tags: фонетика

Почему в русском языке порой пишется одна буква, а читается совершенно другая? Почему мы пишем "что", а говорим "што" и т.д.? Зачем эти сложности?

Comment: Вы не хотите задать подобный же вопрос англичанам или французам? :-)) Здест проявляется традиционный принцип русской орфографии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да всё в общем-то просто. Орфография обычно закрепляет написание какого-то исторического периода, основанное на тогдашнем произношении. Потом произношение меняется. Орфография не может - да и не должна - гнаться за быстрыми колебаниями в произношении. 
Кроме того, надо учитывать и диалектные колебания, часто "литературное" произношение в основе своей имеет диалектные особенности. Так упомянутая вами норма "што" - это московское произношение. В Петербурге до недавнего времени обычным было именно **ч**то, було**ч**ная, коне**ч**но и проч. Сейчас, правда, московская норма становится повсеместной.

Comment: А как правильно произносить слово "булочная"? Через "ч" или через "ш"?

Comment: Но недавнего времени було[шн]ая считалась предпочтительным вариантом, так как было основано на московском гоаоре. Сейчас нормативным стало [чн], но в Москве (и южнее) вполне ещё можно услышать [шн], особенно от лиц старше 50.

Comment: Живу в Тольятти (Поволжье), с самого детства слышал [чн] и устойчивое мнение  о том, что [шн] - это нарочито питерское произношение. // cc: @Nikolja

Answer (score 2):

Сложностей  было  бы  больше,  если  бы  мы  писали  как  говорим.

Answer (score 0):

Исторически сложилось так, что русское правописание основано не на фонетическом принципе, а на грамматическом. Такому принципу следуют и многие другие языки, где приходится запоминать произношение многих букв или сочетаний букв (английский, французский...). Появился и такой раздел языкознания, как орфоэпия, закрепляющий нормы произношения слов.

Comment: Никогда. Принцип русской орфографии - фоно-морфологический (обычно говорят просто "морфологический", что вполне верно). Что такое "грамматический принцип орфографии" я даже представить не могу.

Comment: Я тоже не слыхала о грамматическом принципе. Основных принципов четыре: фонетический, морфологический, традиционный (он же исторический) и дифференциальный.